# rootDirName returning wrong part of the path

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a Gulpfile which runs in the 'theme' folder of my project.

C:\wamp\www\mywebsitename\wp-content\themes\mythemename\gulpfile.js

In the gulpfiule, need to get the local website URL, which is basically just the 'mywebsitename' part of this path.

I have historically used this code to get it successfully:

```
"var rootDirName     = path.basename(__dirname, '../../../');"
```

However I recently re-installed Windows, Node and Gulp, and now that line of code returns 'mythemename' instead of 'mywebsitename', ignoring the '../../../' argument.

If I remove that argument, it stil returns 'mythemename'.

I'm guessing some newer version of Gulp, Node or something in Windows has changed how this method works. Please can anyone suggest why this no longer works, or if there is a better way to always go 3 levels up the file tree from the gulpfile.js directory?

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out myself.

```
const path          = require('path');
var rootDirPath     = path.join(__dirname, '../../../');
var rootDirName     = path.basename(rootDirPath);
var url             = 'http://localhost/' + rootDirName;
```

This will allow you to get the website's URL on localhost in Gulp and do what you need to with it (in my case, using the Critical CSS tool to scan the website and inline all the header CSS).